# Importing firebase-admin gives "cannot resolve" error when installing with poetry

Tags: python, firebase, python-poetry

I'm using poetry for installing dependencies. When I add `firebase-admin = "^5.2.0"` to my .toml file, and run `poetry update && poetry install` it seems to install just fine and shows up in the dependency tree.

However, when I go to import firebase_admin in my project, I get the error:

`import firebase_admin could not be resolved`

I've tried:

- Removing firebase-admin
- Checking poetry was up to date
- Deleting the .lock file, and the poetry venv

Just installing firebase-admin with pip worked and the import resolved.

Poetry Version: 1.1.14
Python Version: 3.9.13
I'm using a Windows 11 and editing in VS Code.

Thank you for any suggestions on how to resolve this!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.